# PHP How to make a valid hex escape sequences from a integer

Tags: php, hex

In short I have a number, Example $n = 90.
I need to make this number a HEX char, For $n = 90 the string would be "\x5a".
So far I have tried:

```
$n = 30;
$h = dechex($n);
$s = "\x" . $h;
```

But it is not escaped by PHP correctly -__-

The Point of this is I am trying to send a command to a Network ESC/POS printer, The full code is:

```
public function lineSpacing($n = 30) {
    $h = dechex($n);
    $this->buff("\x1b\x33\x" . $h);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated ^__^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I still cant find out how to construct \xHH correctly but

```
public function lineSpacing($n = 30) {
    $c = chr($n);
    $this->buff("\x1b\x33" . $c);
}
```

Is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that has PHP interprets **"\x"** on your string has literal characters, not an escape sequence...

For the past 6 hours i have been dealing with the same issue and your question made me realize the real problem.

Let's say you have a string filled with escape sequences (hex):

```
$epsonCmd_OK = "\x1B\x21\x08";
```

The above string is not the same has this one ($final):

```
$epsonCmd_NOTOK = "\x1b\x21\x";
$hex = "08";
$final = $epsonCmd_NOTOK . $hex;
```

Why?

Let's take a look!
The first string **$epsonCmd_OK** has 3 chars, the hex's **\x1B**, **\x21** and **\x08**. (all with escape sequences)

The second string **$epsonCmd_NOTOK** has 4 chars, the hex's **\x1B**, **\x21** plus the literal characters "\" and "x".

Because **"\x"** is no escape sequence, PHP treats it has 2 normal characters, not has the beginning of an escape sequence. When you then concatenate **$hex** to the string you are just adding more characters to the string because the PHP interpreter has all already determined that **"\x"** are characters, and not the beginning of an escape sequence.

In this specific case the best way to do this is to use **PHP chr()** function (just has @leumas95 stated):

```
$epsonCmd_NOTOK = "\x1b\x21"; // no "\x" needed here
$dec = 8;
$final = $epsonCmd_NOTOK . chr($dec); // now $final is equivalent to $epsonCmd_OK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 30;
$h = dechex($n);
$s = "\\x" . $h;
```

Read up on [escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: the code above is still not escaping correctly, the printer just prints x3c, unlike if I typed \x3c, where it recognizes the command.

Comment: Hm, perhaps the printer gives a special meaning to \\ too. You could try \\\\.

Comment: I just updated the question, I am trying to build a escape sequence not escape the escape sequence.

Comment: using \\\\\\\ makes it print \\\x3c :(

Comment: I said just 4 of them, not 7. I think I still don't really get what you are trying to accomplice.

Comment: Yea sorry I didn't see the edit, \\\\ gives \x3c.

I am not trying to send "\x3c" to the printer, I want PHP to interpreted the hex string and send it. \xHH is interpreted as a UTF-8 character by PHP from my understanding.

Comment: Ah, well that was not very clear from your question imo, but ok. I'm not sure if you can use escape sequences in that way. I don't think so. If your printer needs UTF-8 input you should use something like `utf8_encode()`.